# Difference between run thread on a static method vs running with class object

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to threading, I have following code:

```
import threading
import time


class mythread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Started")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reply = mythread()
    reply.setDaemon(True)
    reply.run()

    for _ in range(10):
        print('waiting {} ...'.format(_))
        time.sleep(1)
```

I get following output:

```
Started
Started
Started
Started
Started
```

And I have another piece of code:

```
import threading
import time

def replymessage():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Started")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reply_message_thread = threading.Thread(target=replymessage, daemon=True)
    reply_message_thread.start()

    for _ in range(10):
        print('waiting {} ...'.format(_))
        time.sleep(1)
```

here the output is:

```
waiting 0 ...
waiting 1 ...
Started
waiting 2 ...
Started
waiting 3 ...
Started
waiting 4 ...
Started
```

In second the thread is running along with main thread, but not in first case. Why is that? What should I do in first case so output is like second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you are not starting a thread at all.  You are calling the `run()` function in your main thread, where it blocks.  To start the thread, you need to call

```
reply.start()
```

not

```
reply.run()
```